# Unity Memory Leak Issue: TLS Allocator ALLOC_TEMP_TLS Error When Constantly Reloading Texture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory-leaks

I'm working on a Unity project where I need to constantly reload a texture onto a plane.The Textures are rendered by an external program, and I need to display them in Unity in "real time". However, after a few reloads, I encounter a memory leak issue that results in the following error message:

```
TLS Allocator ALLOC_TEMP_TLS, underlying allocator ALLOC_TEMP_MAIN has unfreed allocations, size 4096
```

The code is executed around 10 times a second.
Here's the relevant part of my code where the texture gets reloaded:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class UpdateTexture : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture2D tex2D;

    void Start()
    {
        tex2D = new Texture2D(2, 2);
    }

    public void Load(string textureDataPath, GameObject g)
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadTextureAsync(textureDataPath, g));
    }

    IEnumerator LoadTextureAsync(string textureDataPath, GameObject g)
    {
        byte[] textureData;
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(textureDataPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            int numBytesToRead = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
            textureData = new byte[numBytesToRead];
            yield return new WaitUntil(() => fs.Read(textureData, 0, numBytesToRead) > 0);
        }

        if (tex2D != null) Destroy(tex2D); 
        tex2D = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        tex2D.LoadImage(textureData);

        ApplyTextureToGameObject(g, tex2D);
    }

    void ApplyTextureToGameObject(GameObject g, Texture2D texture)
    {
        Renderer renderer = g.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        if (renderer != null)
        {
            if (renderer.material != null)
            {
                Destroy(renderer.material); 
            }
            renderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Unlit/Texture"));
            renderer.material.mainTexture = texture;
        }
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (tex2D != null) Destroy(tex2D);
        Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        if (renderer != null && renderer.material != null)
        {
            Destroy(renderer.material);
        }
    }
}
'''
```

Comment: could you not build up a dictionary of loaded textures rather than constantly reload? 10x a second seems a lot to be changing textures

Comment: The Textures are rendered by an external program, and I need to display them in Unity in "real time".

Comment: ah .. ick..   if you keep a handle you could try dispose the old texture before loading a new ? (havent looked)